# Twitter Bot to Likes some tweets using ruby

Tags: ruby, api, twitter

I am a Ruby beginner currently working on Twitter API's.

So far I learned how to tweet and look for tweets using twitter bot with [The Twitter Ruby Gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter).

```
def follow_hello(client)
    client.search("#Hello_World", result_type: "recent").take(20).map do |tweet|
      client.follow(tweet.user)
    end
end
```

How can I "Like" all the 20 tweets with the `#Hello_World`?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
client.search('#Hello_World', result_type: "recent").take(25).each do |like|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a "[favorite](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter/Twitter/REST/Favorites#favorite-instance_method)" call that you can make, by passing it a collection of tweets.

Although I can't test it out at the moment, something like this *should* work:

```
var tweets = client.search("#Hello_World", result_type: "recent").take(20)

client.favorite(tweets)
```